# How to combine these two credentials Queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to make this two queries into one query. The purpose of the query is to check if the credentials match in either of the table "user_credentials" or "workers". How can I do so?

> SELECT user_name FROM user_credentials WHERE user_name = '$user_email'
>   AND password = '$user_password'
>
> SELECT user_name FROM workers WHERE user_name = '$user_email'
>   AND password = '$user_password'

Comment: Have you considered `union all`?

Comment: yup, but they have different attributes/columns.

Comment: . . You are selecting `username` from each and no other columns.  This should be okay for a `union all`.

Comment: I think it has to be unique, should be `union` than `union all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT user_name FROM user_credentials WHERE user_name = '$user_email' AND password = '$user_password'

union

SELECT user_name FROM workers WHERE user_name = '$user_email' AND password = '$user_password'
```

then check `mysqli_num_rows` or `mysql_num_rows`